# How do edit my profile on Careers 2.0?

Tags: support, jobs

Ok, this might turn out to be embarrassing, but I'll post it anyway: I wish to add more information to my profile on Careers 2.0, but I can't seem to find any suitable `<form>` on the site...

- Where do I enter summary, experience, education, etc.?
- How do I pick "best answers"?

Also, I am almost certain I added a summary and "likes" on Careers 1.0, but none of this seems to have been carried over to 2.0. Is this by design, or is my profile bugged?

Answer (score 2):

First go to your profile.

[image]

Next you will find an `edit` link right next to each section of information or an `add to ...` link at the end of each list like education and experience.

under the section title `Stack Exchange Network` you will find a `add top answers` link.

Answer (score 1):

In general, [see Ralph's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80624/how-do-edit-my-profile-on-careers-2-0/80628#80628).  If that doesn't work, and you're sure you had a profile before the switch to Careers 2.0, send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com and we'll try to get you sorted out.  It's possible some accounts may not have been migrated correctly.

Comment: If you had an account and used the invite link to ask for an invite, would that be enough? Also, how long does it take to get invites out?

Comment: @Diago requesting an invite doesn't guarantee that you'll get one -- we're also going to look at activity on SO and other programming-related sites.  If you had an old CV and can't get to it now, send us an email so we can figure out what went wrong.